# Characteristic Curves of $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}+(a+b u)\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I reach to a problem in engineering, and I really appreciate if some body can help me. what is the characteristic curves of following quasi_linear equation:

$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}+(a+b u)\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=0$ which $a$ and $b$ are constant.

Comment: You want "the method of characteristics": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}+(a+b u)\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=0$$
The set of characteristic equations is :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{a+bu}=\frac{du}{0}$$
Necessarily $du=0 \quad\to\quad u=c_1 \quad$ which is the equation of a first characteristic curve.

A second characteristic curve comes from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{a+bc_1} \quad\to\quad (a+bc_1)t-x=c_2$

The equation of the second characteristic curve is : $\quad (a+bu)t-x=c_2$

The general solution od the PDE expressed on the form of an implicit equation is :

$$\Phi\left(u\:,\:(a+bu)t-x \right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

Solving this implicit equation for the first variable leads to an equivalent form of the general solution :
$$u=f\left((a+bu)t-x \right)$$
where $f$ is any differentiable function.

Since $u$ appears in both terms of the equation, in the general case $u(x,t)$ cannot be expressed on explicit form insofar the boundary conditions are missing in the wording of the question. Without specified boundary condition, it isn't possible to go further and see if a particular solution can be explicitly derived.